# Flipper plugins and Expo 45

Tags: react-native, expo, flipper

I have Flipper up and running with a development build from expo 45 with eas build.

React DevTools is running perfectly and getting detected by flipper. But I need to algo see the logs of redux on Flipper as I´m using @reduxjs/toolkit.

I installed redux-flipper on my app, built it again but the plugin is not detecting my app.

This is how I added redux-flipper middleware on my store:

```
if (__DEV__) {
  const createDebugger = require("redux-flipper").default;
  middlewares.push(createDebugger());
}

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
  },
  middleware: middlewares,
});
```